# select and delete rows from specific row to end of table in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table where columns are:

```
id, date, sold, rev
```

I like to get row where `date column = some date`, and I'd like to delete all rows from that row till end of the table. The pseudo-code that comes to my mind goes something like this:

```
$date = specific date;

$conn->prepare (select id from table where date = $date)
while (id is not last)
{
  $conn->delete (current id from table);
}
```

Comment: Wait, if you have an array of IDs, have you considered just running one query to delete all the rows with date=$date and id=in your array?

Comment: Or couldn't you just `DELETE FROM table WHERE date = $date`? Can you write PHP instead of just pseudo?

Comment: because its not just one row I'm trying to delete, i need to delete from specific point in that table to end of the table. and i should have pointed out dates are in order and no same dates

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, I will use

```
"DELETE FROM table_name WHERE date != $date"
```

Or is you want to delete from that date to the end of the table provided the date is in an arranged order like descending or ascending you can use

```
"DELETE FROM table_name WHERE date >= $date"
```

or

```
"DELETE FROM table_name WHERE date <= $date"
```

Comment: oh i didn't know you could use operator on date in pdo statements

Comment: oh you can, try the answer and find for yourself

Comment: so i don't need any loops? i can just arrange the order of table by dates and run delete from table where date >= $date ?

Comment: Yes you can, you give it a try

Answer (score 0):

Id's in mysql are inserted in form of incremental order. So you can select your required id by:

`select id from table where date = $date;`

once you get the id (assume in variable $id) then execute the query:

`delete from table_name where id >= $id;`

it will delete all the rows till the end of the table from your required row.
it can also be deleted by providing date conidtion (only if you are sure that dates are inserted in incremental order):

`delete from table_name where date >= $date;`

Comment: ok so i found out there is statement that does "INSERT INTO table (date, rev, sold) VALUES (?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE rev = VALUES(?), sold = VALUES(?)" with this i have to no longer delete records and re-add. but now the only problem i have is "ON DUPLICATE KEY", how can i specify KEY to be a date column and not id. further more when i ran this query i got following error. --> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Comment: ok i am not sure but i think that you need to update your row, where the `date` column is your required value?
why don't you try this:
`UPDATE table_name SET column_name = your_value WHERE date = your_required_date;` <br>
but if multiple row has the same date, then it will update all these rows. So make sure that the date does not repeat :)

Comment: no dates never repeat, i haven't explained properly what i was doing so let me do that since someone here might have better solution, basically i get a file with date sold and revenue report of from today till next year, and of course the future dates revenue is based on how many reservation we have so far, and since that value is changing everyday based on how many new reservations comes in or canceled that report is pulled everyday and inserted in to database, thats why majority of the dates will be same with just new revenue and sold values, and only few dates new compared to yesterday.

Comment: everyone thanks for all your input, turns out i was able to do it even easier way, using REPLACE INTO.... now only one problem i have is i need to figure out a way to get the value that was already there and subtract it with new value before its updated, and store the difference into another table, ex. if today for date 07/10/2015 revenue is $150.00 and when i upload the new report and revenue for 07/10/2015 is now $200.00 before i replace 150 with 200 i need to do 200-150 and store 50 into separate  table.